# Responding to harsh criticization

Tags: source-identification

Today I have been told about a narration of a past great scholar, to the effect of he has harshly and wrongly criticized and his only response was: “If you are right Allah shall help me, if you are wrong Allah shall forgive you.”

Does anybody the full account of the narration?

Comment: Do you have any additional information? Like context, have you heard it or read it in tafseer or ... ? It sounds a bit disarranged the "negation" of this sounds like a better fit -at least in Arabic linguistics-: "If I'm wrong Allah may help/guide me, if I'm right may Allah forgive you" ...

Comment: @ Sadly no other context. The context was controlling oneself in such situations and along many other examples, this one was also given.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar story being told but no confirmation it is true.
Even scholars say it cannot be true.

It says that some Jewish man asked Ibrahim Ibn Adham: "which is better? Your beard or this dog's tail?"
The calm answer was: "if I will go to heaven it means my beard is better. Otherwise, the dog's tail is better".

There is criticisms on this story and disagreement. Not sure if this the one you are looking for.

However, the Quran in surat AlForqan aya 63 says something similar in meaning of what you are looking for. Not exactly. Please refer to it and to the tafseer.

The text in Arabic as I found it from some site:

يهودي معه كلب -واليهود لطالما استفزوا المسلمين يريدون أن يوقعوهم في شَرَكِهم- يمر على إبراهيم بن أدهم عليه رحمة الله ذلكم المؤمن، فيقول له: ألحيتك -يا إبراهيم - أطهر من ذنب هذا الكلب، أم ذنب الكلب أطهر من لحيتك؟
فما كان منه إلا أن قال -بهدوء المؤمن الواثق بموعود الله عز وجل-: إن كانت في الجنة فهي أطهر من ذنب كلبك، وإن كانت في النار لذنب كلبك أطهر منها.